# Using Isotope.js with React to create a masonry layout with filters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-isotope, gatsby

I'm building a blog with Gatsby and I'm trying to implement a masonry grid with filters to display my posts. In the past, I did this by using Isotope.js so I went with that again. But, it's not really working. I'm still very new to React so I can't figure out what wrong.

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
import React from 'react';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { Link, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import Isotope from "isotope-layout/js/isotope";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class FilterGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFilterChange = this.onFilterChange.bind(this);
  }

  // Click Function
  onFilterChange = (newFilter) => {
    if (this.iso === undefined) {
      this.iso = new Isotope('#grid-container', {
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: "fitRows",
        percentPosition: true,
        fitRows: {
          gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
        }
      });
    }
    if(newFilter === '*') {
      this.iso.arrange({ filter: `*` });
    } else {
      this.iso.arrange({ filter: `.${newFilter}` });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.node

    return(
      // Filter Buttons
      <section className="section">
        <div className="button-group filter-button-group grid-filters">
          <div className="tabs is-centered is-toggle">
            <ul id="portfolio-flters">
              <li data-filter="*" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("*")}}>All</li>
              <li data-filter="brandy" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("brandy")}}>Brandy</li>
              <li data-filter="cachaça" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("cachaça")}}>Cachaça</li>
              <li data-filter="gin" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("gin")}}>Gin</li>
              <li data-filter="mexcal" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("mezcal")}}>Mezcal</li>
              <li data-filter="rum" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("rum")}}>Rum</li>
              <li data-filter="tequila" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("tequila")}}>Tequila</li>
              <li data-filter="whiskey" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("whiskey")}}>Whiskey</li>
              <li data-filter="vodka" onClick={() => {this.onFilterChange("vodka")}}>Vodka</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div className="grid" id="grid-container">
        <div className="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div className="gutter-sizer"></div>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <div className="grid-item {post.frontmatter.category}">
              <Link to={post.fields.slug}>
                  <figure className="image">
                      <Img fluid={post.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
                      <figcaption>
                          <h4 className="title is-4">{post.frontmatter.title}</h4>
                      <p className="grid-item-blurb">{post.frontmatter.description}</p>
                      </figcaption>
                  </figure>
              </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
    )
  }
}

FilterGrid.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMarkdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      edges: PropTypes.array,
    }),
  }),
}

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query = {graphql`
      query FilterGridQuery {
        allMarkdownRemark (
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}
          filter: { frontmatter: {templateKey: {eq: "recipe"}}}
          ) {
        edges{
          node{
            id
            frontmatter {
               title
               date
               description
               image {
                 childImageSharp {
                   resize(width: 1500, height: 1500) {
                     src
                   }
                   fluid(maxWidth: 786) {
                     ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                   }
                 }
               }
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `}
  render={(data, count) => <FilterGrid data={data} count={count} />}
  />

)
```

I'm only trying to use Isotope.js because I've used it before but if there's a better way to do this please let me know! This is driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a masonry layout you may want to use [react-masonry-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component), but as far as using Isotope and React together you're likely to run into issues because React doesn’t expect other tools to manipulate the DOM, meanwhile Isotope expects all of your state to be in the DOM. They're like oil and water.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the react-masonry-component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
const posts = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.node
```

Didn't you mean to get `allMarkdownRemark.edges` instead? `allMarkdownRemark.node` is definitely undefined.

Comment: Oh right, that was it. Thanks! It's still not displaying right though but that's a different issue.